# "RuntimeError: shape '[1600, 3, 16, 8, 8, 28]' is invalid for input of size 160563200" with ConvMixerSwinV2 model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am working to implement the ConvMixerSwinV2 model. I have tried to implement the model in my code and train it on the CIFAR100 dataset, but I am getting a lot of errors.

The latest error that I am getting is the following:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-3b522f5841c4> in <cell line: 189>()
    199 
    200     optimizer.zero_grad()
--> 201     outputs = model(inputs)
    202     loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    203 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-95-3b522f5841c4> in forward(self, x)
    136     x = x.permute(0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5)  # Trasponi gli assi per raggruppare i patch
    137     x = x.reshape(-1, self.swin_transformer.patch_size[0] * self.swin_transformer.patch_size[1], C)
--> 138     x = self.swin_transformer(x)
    139     x = x.mean(dim=[1, 2])
    140     x = self.classifier(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-95-3b522f5841c4> in forward(self, x)
    104     x = x.reshape(-1, self.img_size[0] // self.patch_size[0], self.img_size[1] // self.patch_size[1], self.embed_dim)
    105     for layer in self.layers:
--> 106         x = layer(x)
    107     x = x.mean(dim=[1, 2])
    108     x = self.linear(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-95-3b522f5841c4> in forward(self, x)
     66     B, C, H, W = x.shape  # Get batch size, channels, height, and width
     67     x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  # Permute axes to get the correct format
---> 68     x = x.reshape(B, H // self.patch_size[0], W // self.patch_size[1], self.patch_size[0], self.patch_size[1], C)
     69     x = x.permute(0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5)
     70     x = x.reshape(-1, self.patch_size[0] * self.patch_size[1], C)

RuntimeError: shape '[1600, 3, 16, 8, 8, 28]' is invalid for input of size 160563200
```

I have tried to find a solution online, but I have not been able to find anything that helps me. I would be grateful if you could help me to understand what I am doing wrong and how to fix this error.

I have attached the code that I am using:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Define the SwinTransformerAttention model
class SwinTransformerAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate):
        super(SwinTransformerAttention, self).__init__()

        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.qkv_bias = qkv_bias
        self.drop_path_rate = drop_path_rate

        # Initialize the layers for Q, K, and V transformations
        self.q = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim * num_heads, bias=qkv_bias)
        self.k = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim * num_heads, bias=qkv_bias)
        self.v = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim * num_heads, bias=qkv_bias)
        
        # Initialize the softmax and dropout layers
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drop_path_rate)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Apply linear transformations to input for Q, K, and V
        q = self.q(x)
        k = self.k(x)
        v = self.v(x)

        B, H, W, C = q.shape  # Store the original shape
        
        # Reshape Q, K, and V for attention calculation
        q = q.reshape(B, H * W, self.num_heads, self.embed_dim // self.num_heads)
        k = k.reshape(B, H * W, self.num_heads, self.embed_dim // self.num_heads)
        v = v.reshape(B, H * W, self.num_heads, self.embed_dim // self.num_heads)

        # Calculate attention scores and apply softmax
        attn = self.softmax(q @ k.transpose(-1, -2))
        attn = self.dropout(attn)

        # Calculate the output using attention scores and V
        out = attn @ v
        out = out.reshape(B, H, W, -1)

        return out

# Define the SwinTransformerBlock model
class SwinTransformerBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_size, patch_size, embed_dim, num_heads, mlp_ratio, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate):
        super(SwinTransformerBlock, self).__init__()

        self.img_size = img_size
        self.patch_size = patch_size
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.mlp_ratio = mlp_ratio
        self.qkv_bias = qkv_bias
        self.drop_path_rate = drop_path_rate

        # Initialize Layer Normalization for the first normalization step
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(embed_dim)
        # Initialize the SwinTransformerAttention module
        self.attn = SwinTransformerAttention(embed_dim, num_heads, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate)
        # Initialize Layer Normalization for the second normalization step
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(embed_dim)
        
        # Initialize the Multi-Layer Perceptron (MLP)
        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embed_dim, int(embed_dim * mlp_ratio)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(int(embed_dim * mlp_ratio), embed_dim),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        B, C, H, W = x.shape  # Get batch size, channels, height, and width
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  # Permute axes for correct format
        x = x.reshape(B, H // self.patch_size[0], W // self.patch_size[1], self.patch_size[0], self.patch_size[1], C)  # Reshape into patches
        x = x.permute(0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5)  # Permute axes to group patches
        x = x.reshape(-1, self.patch_size[0] * self.patch_size[1], C)  # Reshape for attention calculation
        x = self.attn(x)  # Apply the attention mechanism
        x = x.reshape(B, H // self.patch_size[0], W // self.patch_size[1], -1)  # Reshape back to patch grid
        x = x.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)  # Permute axes back to the original format
        x = self.norm1(x)  # Apply Layer Normalization
        residual = x  # Save the residual for later use
        x = self.mlp(x)  # Apply the MLP
        x = x + residual  # Add back the residual connection
        x = self.norm2(x)  # Apply Layer Normalization again
        return x

# Define the SwinTransformerV2 model
class SwinTransformerV2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, img_size, patch_size, embed_dim, depths, num_heads, mlp_ratio, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate):
        super(SwinTransformerV2, self).__init__()

        self.img_size = img_size
        self.patch_size = patch_size
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.depths = depths
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.mlp_ratio = mlp_ratio
        self.qkv_bias = qkv_bias
        self.drop_path_rate = drop_path_rate

        # Initialize a list of SwinTransformerBlock layers
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(self.depths):
            self.layers.append(SwinTransformerBlock(img_size, patch_size, embed_dim, num_heads, mlp_ratio, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate))
        
        # Initialize the final linear layer for classification
        self.linear = nn.Linear(embed_dim, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(-1, self.img_size[0] // self.patch_size[0], self.img_size[1] // self.patch_size[1], self.embed_dim)
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x)  # Apply each SwinTransformerBlock layer
        x = x.mean(dim=[1, 2])  # Global average pooling
        x = self.linear(x)  # Classification layer
        return x

# Define the ConvMixerSwinV2 model
class ConvMixerSwinV2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, patch_size, embed_dim, depths, num_heads, mlp_ratio, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate):
        super(ConvMixerSwinV2, self).__init__()

        # Initialize the first convolutional layer
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        # Initialize the SwinTransformerV2 model
        self.swin_transformer = SwinTransformerV2(img_size, patch_size, embed_dim, depths, num_heads, mlp_ratio, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate)
        # Initialize the final linear layer for classification
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(128, 100)  # Adjust the output dimension for your specific classification task

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)  # Apply the initial convolution
        B, C, H, W = x.shape
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  # Transpose the axes
        x = x.reshape(B, H // self.swin_transformer.patch_size[0], self.swin_transformer.patch_size[0], W // self.swin_transformer.patch_size[1], self.swin_transformer.patch_size[1], C)
        x = x.permute(0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5)  # Transpose axes to group patches
        x = x.reshape(-1, self.swin_transformer.patch_size[0] * self.swin_transformer.patch_size[1], C)  # Reshape for attention calculation
        x = self.swin_transformer(x)  # Apply the SwinTransformerV2 model
        x = x.mean(dim=[1, 2])  # Global average pooling
        x = self.classifier(x)  # Classification layer
        return x

# Check if a GPU is available and set the correct device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Provide all the necessary values for creating SwinTransformerV2
img_size = (224, 224)  # Input image size (upscale to 224x224 for compatibility with SwinTransformerV2)
patch_size = (8, 8)    # Patch size
embed_dim = 128        # Embedding dimension
depths = 12            # Number of blocks
num_heads = 32         # Number of attention heads
mlp_ratio = 4          # Inner MLP dimension ratio
qkv_bias = True        # Bias for QKV operations
drop_path_rate = 0.2   # Drop path rate for dropout

# Hyperparameters
batch_size = 32
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 5
num_classes = 100  # Number of classes in the classification task

# Hyperparameters
batch_size = 25  # Mini-batch size
accumulation_steps = 5  # Number of mini-batches to accumulate before performing an update

# Image transformations
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),  # Pre-calculated mean and standard deviation values
])

# Load the CIFAR-100 dataset for training
train_dataset = datasets.CIFAR100(root='./data', train=True, transform=transform, download=True)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Load the CIFAR-100 dataset for testing
test_dataset = datasets.CIFAR100(root='./data', train=False, transform=transform, download=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Create the model and move the weights to the GPU
model = ConvMixerSwinV2(patch_size, embed_dim, depths, num_heads, mlp_ratio, qkv_bias, drop_path_rate).to(device)

# Define the optimizer and the loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Model training
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train().to(device)
    total_loss = 0.0
    mini_batch_count = 0  # Counter for mini-batch accumulation
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # RESET GRADIENT AT THE BEGINNING OF EACH EPOCH

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs = inputs.to(device)  # Move data to the GPU if available
        labels = labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        loss.backward()  # Accumulate gradient for subsequent updates

        mini_batch_count += 1

        if mini_batch_count == accumulation_steps:
            # Perform weight update after accumulating gradients for the defined number of mini-batches
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()  # RESET GRADIENT AFTER UPDATE

            mini_batch_count = 0

        total_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)

        # Perform a final update if accumulation is not complete for the last batch
        if mini_batch_count > 0:
            optimizer.step()

    average_loss = total_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Average Loss: {average_loss:.4f}")

    # Valutazione del modello sulla fase di validazione
    model.eval()
    total_correct = 0
    total_samples = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
      for inputs, labels in test_loader:
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        total_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        total_samples += labels.size(0)

accuracy = total_correct / total_samples
print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Validation Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}")
```

Here are the attempts I made to try to correct the code:

Modified the dimensions of x within the SwinTransformerBlock blocks to ensure that the dimensions are consistent with the number of patches.
Added permutations and resizing to the correct dimensions inside the SwinTransformerBlock blocks to properly handle the attention calculation steps.
Added comments to explain the purpose of each modification made to the code.
Corrected the implementation of the training part, including handling gradient accumulation.
However, it seems that there are still some errors in the implementation, as the "shape is invalid for input of size" error continues to appear.

The expectations for this code implementation are to successfully create and train a ConvMixerSwinV2 model for image classification on the CIFAR-100 dataset. The ConvMixerSwinV2 model combines the ConvMixer architecture with a Swin Transformer backbone, aiming to achieve improved performance in image understanding tasks.

Here's what the code is expected to do:

Data Loading: Load the CIFAR-100 dataset and set up data loaders for training and testing.

Model Definition: Define the ConvMixerSwinV2 model, which consists of a convolutional layer, a Swin Transformer backbone, and a linear classification head.

Training Loop: Train the model using a proper training loop. The loop includes forward and backward passes, gradient accumulation, optimization, and loss calculation.

Evaluation: Evaluate the trained model on the test dataset to measure its accuracy and generalization performance.

Expected Output: Over the course of training, the model's average loss should decrease, indicating that the model is learning. After training, the model's accuracy on the test dataset should be reasonable for image classification tasks.

Validation and Debugging: Throughout the process, debugging any runtime errors, ensuring proper tensor shapes and dimensions, and verifying the correctness of transformations and computations are key expectations.

Comment: Just a thought, is the integer division maybe a problem and you loose some elements because of it so it does not add up anymore?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could infer from the errors and code you provided, I guess the tensor `x` that enters `SwinTransformerBlock.forward()` has (a) a wrong order of dimensions and (b) a wrong size.

I can reproduce your exact error with the following code, which reimplements the beginning of your `SwinTransformerBlock.forward()` method, as well as providing a tensor of the size that I assume is your input `x`:

```py
import torch

# Values implied by the error message
x = torch.zeros((1600, 28, 28, 128))
patch_size = (8, 8)

# Code from `SwinTransformerBlock.forward()` follows
B, C, H, W = x.shape  # Get batch size, channels, height, and width
x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  # Permute axes for correct format
x = x.reshape(B, H // patch_size[0], W // patch_size[1], patch_size[0], patch_size[1], C)  # Reshape into patches

# >>> RuntimeError: shape '[1600, 3, 16, 8, 8, 28]' is invalid for input of size 160563200
```

I notice two things here:

- For CIFAR image data, I would assume that height and width are the same value. In your case, as it seems, you have 28 channels, a height of 28 and a width of 128. Shouldn't it be 128 channels, a height of 28 and a width of 28 instead?
- Even if you had a matching height and width of 28 pixels instead, the line with `x.reshape()` would fail, as 28 is not integer-divisible without remainder by a patch size of 8. In other words: an image of size 28x28 cannot be subdivided into patches of size 8x8.

**Suggestion:** Check the shape of `x` that goes into `SwinTransformerBlock.forward()`: what shape do you see and what shape would you expect? You can do this with your debugger or with an added `print(x.shape)`. Note that the error might happen in any of your Swin Transformer blocks, not necessarily in the first one (I did not dig that far into your code).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your response. I managed to solve it and experiment with various things (I'm currently working with DenseNet). I have another question. How can I create two plots, perhaps using matplotlib, one for the test and train Loss and one for the test and train Accuracy?

```
loss_values_train = []
loss_values_test = []
accuracy_values_train = []
accuracy_values_test = []


for epoch in range(2):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    print(f'Epoca numero: {epoch + 1}')

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    loss_values_train.append(running_loss / len(train_loader))
    loss_values_train.append(running_loss / len(test_loader))
    accuracy_values_train.append(100 * correct / total)


    scheduler.step()

    if running_loss < best_loss:
        print(f"Loss migliorato da {best_loss/1000} a {running_loss / 1000}. Salvo il checkpoint.")
        best_loss = running_loss
        save_checkpoint(epoch, model, optimizer, best_loss)


model.eval()
```

Thank you very much for the help.
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

I managed to print all the data on a graph.

```
# Definisci le liste per salvare le metriche di addestramento e test
train_loss_history = []
test_loss_history = []
train_accuracy_history = []
test_accuracy_history = []

# Numeroe epoche su cui si svolgera' l'allenamento
epoche = 50
print(f'Numero di epoche totali: {epoche}')

# Definisci una variabile per tenere traccia dell'accuratezza migliore
best_accuracy = 0.0

# Addestra il modello
for epoch in range(epoche):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct_train = 0
    total_train = 0

    print(f'Epoca numero: {epoch + 1}/{epoche}')

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()

        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total_train += labels.size(0)
        correct_train += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    train_loss_history.append(running_loss / len(train_loader))
    print(f"Loss di allenamento: {(running_loss / len(train_loader)):.3f}")

    # Calcolo dell'accuratezza di allenamento
    train_accuracy = (correct_train / total_train) * 100
    train_accuracy_history.append(train_accuracy)
    print(f"Accuratezza di allenamento: {train_accuracy:.3f}%")

    test_loss_history.append(test_loss / len(test_loader))
    print(f"Loss di test: {(test_loss / len(test_loader)):.3f}")

    test_accuracy = (correct_test / total_test) * 100
    test_accuracy_history.append(test_accuracy)
    print(f"Accuratezza di test: {test_accuracy:.3f}%")
```

Now I have another issue; during the first 10 epochs, the test and training accuracy converge well without any problems.

However, after the tenth epoch, the test accuracy is disrupted by severe overfitting. I tried to let it continue up to 50 epochs, but by the end, I have a training accuracy of 99% and a test accuracy of 50%.

I've already tried adding BatchNormalization2D and BatchNormalization1D, dropout, decreasing learning rate (LR), and weight decay.